# White flashes and white screen of death after the app opening after adding redux-persist

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm getting white flashes and white screen of death after the app is opened second time after adding `redux-persist`. 
Version of "redux-persist" is "^5.10.0".

Here is my `App.js` file:

```
    import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
    import {store, persistor } from './redux/store'

    export default class App extends React.Component {

  renderLoading = ()=> {
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
    </View>  
  }

      render() {
        return( 
          <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={this.renderLoading()} persistor={persistor}>
              <AppContainer/>
            </PersistGate>
          </Provider>
        )  
      }
    }
```

Here is my ./redux/store file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist"
import reducers from './index';

import bindAuthEvents from '../auth/redux/bindEvents';
import bindTrackingEvents from '../tracking/redux/bindEvents';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
  }

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);

export const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(persistedReducer);

const dispatch = event => store.dispatch(event) 
const getState = () => store.getState()

bindAuthEvents(dispatch, getState);
bindTrackingEvents(dispatch, getState);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

What can be the problem? and how is possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue but I solved using a loading component.

In the emulator it happens eventually but in physical devices not.